# Generating rows and columns based on input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a "Battleship" like program.

This is what I have so far.

```
class Start: 
    def play(rows, columns):
        for i in rows: 
            for j in columns: 
                print("O")
print("Testing")
rowinput = input("rows: ")
colinput = input("columns: ")
s = start()
s.play(rowinput, colinput)
```

This is the error code I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/OfficeUser/Documents/battleship.py", line 12, in <module>
s.play(rowinput, colinput)
TypeError: play() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My question is: How do I implement a row and column generation based on user input via `input()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods of class instances take the instance of the class as first argument.

Add `self` to the definition of `play`. The class instance gets passed when you call the method, so you need to handle that in your method definition:

```
def play(self, rows, columns):
    #...
```

There are other bugs waiting to go off, like: you'll need to cast your inputs to `int`, then you would need to use `range` in your loops:

```
for i in range(rows): 
    for j in range(columns): 
        print("O")
```

Comment: I got an output of just "O" when adding self.

Comment: based on the input gathered, lets say row = 6 and column = 6, you will get a grid of 6x6

Comment: Yes, kinda weird since I remember using self with other projects and it working perfectly fine.

Comment: This was good. I managed to get the desired input. But what are the i and j for? Are they placeholders for the for-loops?

Comment: Use them in the loop directly. Like `print(i, j)`

Comment: Alright, thank you for the assistance; much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call `s.play(rowinput, colinput)`, the object "s" is also passed (implicitly) to the function "play" (as it's first argument). That's what the error is saying that three arguments are being passed to function play, but the signature says that it accepts only two. Now in python the convention is to use the name "self" for the parameter for the class instance. So just add another parameter to the function, like so

```
def play(self, rows, columns):
```

Comment: I got an output of just "O" when adding self